# jQuery opacity on scroll cuts off

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code, which is designed to change the opacity of an image when a certain scale level is reached, in this case when the image scale is 2, the opacity should decrease again, however it just goes from 1 to 0 and doesn't do a nice transition on scroll.

```
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    $(".exteriorImage img").css({
          transform: 'translate3d(-50%, -'+(scroll/100)+'%, 0) scale('+(100 + scroll/5)/100+')',
          "-webkit-filter": "blur(" + (scroll/100) + "px)",
          filter: "blur(" + (scroll/100) + "px)",
          opacity: 1-(scroll/300)
    });
    var scaleArr = getElementPropety('interiorID', 'transform').split('(')
    scaleStr = scaleArr[1].toString();
    scale = scaleStr.split(',')
    scaleInt = parseFloat(scale, 10);
    $(".interiorImage img").css({
        transform: 'translate3d(-50%, -'+ (scroll/100)+'%, 0) scale('+(100 + scroll/5)/100+')',
        "-webkit-filter": "blur(" - (scroll/100) + "px)",
        filter: "blur(" - (scroll/100) + "px)",
    });
    if (scaleInt < 2) {
        $(".interiorImage img").css({
            opacity: 0+(scroll/300)
        });
    } else {
        document.getElementById('interiorID').style.opacity = '1';
        $(".interiorImage img").css({
            opacity: 1-(scroll/300)
        });
    }
    var currentOpacity = getElementPropety('titleTwoID','opacity');
    $("#titleTwoID").css({
        opacity: 0+(scroll/300),
    });
});
```

More specifically,

```
    if (scaleInt < 2) {
        $(".interiorImage img").css({
            opacity: 0+(scroll/300)
        });
    } else {
        document.getElementById('interiorID').style.opacity = '1';
        $(".interiorImage img").css({
            opacity: 1-(scroll/300)
        });
    }
```

(I don't also need the `document.getElementById('interiorID').style.opacity = '1';`However there is no difference when I have it in or out.

Why does the opacity of my site cut off instead of fade on scroll?

Comment: Can you please add the HTML and CSS as well?

Comment: Please add full code which you tried

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 400) {
        var currScrollPos2 = document.body.scrollTop;
        document.getElementById('test').style.opacity = -currScrollPos2/400 + 2;
    }
});
```